# How to debug background location agents in Windows Phone 8

Tags: geolocation, gps, windows-phone-8, background-process, background-agents

I'm currently developing an app where the device's location should be send to a server. I've worked through [the MSDN articles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) on the background agents and accessing the location. This works so far. My location is transmitted to the server when I've triggered a location change which is farther away than the set MovementThreshold.

However, I've read that testing of background agents can be complicated. If you use the Emulator, you can easily change your device's location very often. But on a real phone, location background services are limited in their idle runtime to 30 minutes and execution of commands should only take up to 25 seconds. Background agents can also be disabled by the user from the phone's settings screen. They are also deactivated, when the agent crashes more than two times in a row. Another limitation is that [inactive background agents are stopped after 4 hours](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), if [they don't update an apps live tile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_ConstraintsforallScheduledTaskTypes).

My app updates a live tiles counter, so I think my background agent should be running up to 14 days without restart from my app. I've tested the app from yesterday to today and saw the background agent running (when looked up from the settings). There was also the small dot in the upper bar visible, indicating that a programm is accessing the phones geo location. However, sometimes the dot vanishes and my background agent is killed for no obvious reasons.

Therefore my question are:

- How can I reliable test geo location on a real device without the need to travel with phone and attached debugging laptop?
- How can I test in a timely manner for the timeout scenarios I've mentioned (30 min, 4hrs, 14 days)?
- How can I check for these two crashs of the background agent?

Comment: "My app updates a live tiles counter, so I think my background agent should be running up to 14 days without restart from my app" This is true on WP7. On WP8, your background agent won't expire as long as the tile is pinned on the user's home screen (if it's not pinned, then the 14 days rule applies)

Comment: Can you give me a source for this information? This would mean that all background agents can run for up to 14 days on WP8 without interruption, if I don't pin the app's tile?

Comment: Not without interruption, I was only talking about the expiration date. The "run 25 seconds every 30 minutes" rule is still applied on WP8. Also, my claim was only partially true: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942(v=vs.105).aspx  `If the Tile for your app is pinned to the phone’s Start screen, the expiration time for your background agent schedule is automatically extended to two weeks whenever your background agent calls Update(ShellTileData) to update the Tile` So you need to explicitly update the tile to postpone the expiration date.

Comment: Ok, I'm updating it depending on the intervall of the MovementTreshold  and check then if the last update was at least 2 hours ago. So in theory I'm out of this 30 min limitation. But you were linking to the periodic task. Is it more suitable for location purposes than the WP8 specific background service for location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've made some missinterpretations of how WP8 defines Background Agents. The new WP8 background agent for location is only active, when the app is running. This means that the app  must not be closed with the back button. However, it can be switched to the home screen with the windows button or with a long hold back button to access other apps from multitasking.

Regarding my questions:

- How can I reliable test geo location on a real device without the need to travel with phone and attached debugging laptop?
- How can I test in a timely manner for the timeout scenarios I've mentioned (30 min, 4hrs, 14 days)?

I still have no suitable solution. You are somewhat limited to testing with real devices and the necessary time required to test your constraints.

- How can I check for these two crashs of the background agent?

I don't know how to check for this programmatically. It may be, that a user can see this crashing app as a blocked app in the list of background tasks of the phone's setting. There should be a way to detect a blocked app from this list with the help from the links I've supplied above.

For my project, I needed a location background agent, which runs even with locked screen or with no open app. Therefore I've used a PeriodicAgent to require the location once every 30 minutes so that I can send it to the server. But be aware that this background agents cannot access your application settings or classes (see [Communication between foreground app and background agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202944%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_CommunicationBetweenForegroundApplicationandBackgroundAgent)).